# New Windows 8 context menu: official name and documentation?

Tags: windows-8, context-menu

Windows 8 has got a new handy context menu which is invoked by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> or by right-clicking the lower-left corner of the desktop:

[image: Win8 context menu]

Strangely enough, it's practically impossible to find any official documentation about it or even what it's called. A couple of third-party sites mention this menu as `Win + X menu` or `Windows Tool Menu`, but googling these terms leads to nothing.

What's this menu called? Is there any official info on this feature?

Comment: Scott Hanselman calls it "Power User or Administrative Tools": http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Windows8ProductivityWhoMovedMyCheeseOhThereItIs.aspx

Comment: I think Microsoft intentionally did not name it since they want to wipe out all references to the old "start menu" Win+X was not available in early pre-release versions of W8, I think they added it to RC/RTM versions to quell the complaints of W8 not having a start menu or an option to enable one.

Answer (score 2):

It's called "Quick Access Menu(QAM)" however I have not any official source for this but on the [Social Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itprogeneral/thread/6526f6db-cb34-4a25-bb21-d0bab7f43221) someone put the question with this name.

Also I have seen this name in [Tweak with Viahal's](http://www.askvg.com/exclusive-how-to-add-new-shortcuts-in-quick-access-menu-win-x-menu-of-windows-8/) blog.

Comment: Yes, I saw that too, but he actually explains why he calls it that: "I personally prefer to call it "Quick Access Menu" similar to Quick Access Toolbar present in Ribbon UI of Windows 8 Explorer or Microsoft Office 2010." [link](http://www.askvg.com/exclusive-customize-new-quick-access-menu-win-x-menu-in-windows-8-add-remove-rename-or-move-shortcuts-and-much-more/)

Comment: QAT official [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940502(v=vs.85).aspx). However you can call it that too.

Comment: @avirk How can you call it QAM, there is Nothing officially released by Microsoft to name this Win+X context menu, other than it is a context menu called by the combo keystroke. It is just some name coined by a internet blogger. The question specifically asks for "official" Name and Documentation, and there is None.

Comment: @Moab I have given link of Technet where the user called it the same that's why I put it as an answer, also I have cleared in my answer that there is no official source I had.

Comment: @avirk "New Windows 8 context menu: official name and documentation?"  you did not answer the question, a user on technet or a blogger is not official, nor is there any official documentation. Normally you give great answers, this is not one of them.

Comment: @Moab if there are not any clue on Official site then I think it suits here. Or not? Although [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdnstudents/archive/2012/09/04/some-useful-keyboard-shortcuts-for-windows-8.aspx) says it start menu :)

Comment: @avirk whole point here at SU is to answer the original question and support with documentation when possible, and the OP specifically asked for documentation or official Name, which neither exist. The OP needs to change the question for your answer to be a real answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing yet, and personally I don't think it's necessary to give this a name, since it's nothing special

Comment: I disagree that it's nothing special, since it is a shortcut to many power user tools in one place.

Comment: is there any other context menu that gets its own name?

Comment: I'm disagreeing with the second part of your answer, not the first. That's what got you the downvote.

Comment: Nah I don't care about the downvote. My point is, if something gets a name other than an app or a window, it should be an important or special feature by itself. No context menu ever get a name because of that.

Comment: And once again, I have nothing against your first part, just your opinion in the second part, which I think is wrong. "It's nothing special" is subjective.

Comment: yeah I know it's subjective, hence the "personally"...

Comment: @Chin +1, there is no "official" name given by Microsoft for Win+X, so yours is the best answer, I agree it is "nothing special" and is called a context menu, a context menu is a context menu, Microsoft has never given names to different context menus.