# Customize the new Windows 8 Tools (Windows + X) context menu?

Tags: windows-8, context-menu

In Windows 8, if you press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> shortcut, you will get a new context menu that contains a lot of useful application shortcuts:

[image: Win8 context menu]

There is little information about it though. We still don't even how [it's officially called](https://superuser.com/questions/494845/new-windows-8-context-menu-official-name-and-documentation).

My question is: can I add/remove/rename shortcuts and items in this menu?

Comment: Yep, you're right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. However, you will need a third-party tool called [Win+X Menu Editor](http://winaero.com/download.php?view.21) for that. To my knowledge, there are no *official* methods or tools to achieve that. But I strongly believe they will be released by Microsoft in the future.

The detailed step-by-step tutorial can be found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/113570/how-to-edit-the-winx-menu-in-windows-8-using-a-free-tool/). What goes on behind the curtain is this:

1. The menu items are regular Windows shortcuts, so you need to create them manually.
2. The shortcuts should be marked as valid for loading with a special tool.
3. Valid shortcuts are copied into the `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\GroupN` directories, where N is a number of the target group (there are 3 groups by default).

The `Win+X Menu Editor` has a nice GUI to make all these operations automatically:

[image: Win+X Menu Editor]

Here is what the menu looks like after I have added the Wordpad link:

[image: Wordpad]

**Update:** As per Karan's request: the special marking of links is made by a tool `hashlnk.exe` ([See Rafael's article](http://www.withinwindows.com/2012/04/04/windows-8-secrets-the-winx-menu-and-its-hashing-algorithm/)). It basically takes the link's *target path* and *command line arguments* and then calculates an integer number based on them. This number is later written inside the link file itself. The `hashlnk` itself is an open source tool written by Rafael Rivera and its source code is [uploaded to the Github](https://github.com/riverar/hashlnk). The main C++ file calculating then hash is [here](https://github.com/riverar/hashlnk/blob/master/hashlnk.cpp), and I can assure you, it does nothing malicious.

Comment: "The shortcuts should be marked as valid for loading with a special tool" - Can you explain further what's happening behind the scenes here, so we can do it manually if we so choose? (The utility's *probably* fine, but not everyone trusts just any 3rd party tool, plus it might not be allowed on some system whereas a manual method would work.)

Comment: @Karan, I have updated the answer.