# Add shortcuts to (Windows + X) context menu

Tags: windows-8, context-menu

I want to add `services.msc` into <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> context menu in windows 8 (x64). I know similar question is in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/494847/customize-the-new-windows-8-tools-windows-x-context-menu) but it's not good with using `Win+X Editor`, because it doesn't add Underlined key for shortcuts that added with that and it's not good without having quickly underlined key. I want do that for maually

Context menu folder is: `C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX`

And hide `desktop.ini` files is as bellows (in `...\WinX\group2\desktop.ini`)

```
[LocalizedFileNames]
1 - Run.lnk=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-12710
4 - Control Panel.lnk=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-4161
5 - Task Manager.lnk=@%SystemRoot%\system32\authui.dll,-12139
3 - Windows Explorer.lnk=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-22067
2 - Search.lnk=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-30517
```

I copied `sevices.msc` shortcut into above path in `group2 folder` and add this line `6 - Sevices.lnk=@%SystemRoot%\system32\sevices.msc,?????` in `desktop.ini` file.

First Question: I don't know If this line
 `6 - Sevices.lnk=@%SystemRoot%\system32\sevices.msc,-?????` that I added is correct or not? Also I don't know what to use instead of `-?????`

Last Question: Why `desktop.ini` contents is not `Sorted`. I triyed to manually sort them but when I restart Explorer again it was become out of order.Why?

Answer (score 1):

The QA that you refer to links out to another Blog post that explains that you cannot simply create Lnk files in that location and have them show up in the menu. They need a `hash` of a special kind adding to the `.lnk` file.

Also, the entries in the `desktop.ini` file clearly bear little resemblance to what appears in the menu. Certainly the numbers do not correspond to their position for example. In mine, there are two entries for PowerShell neither of which even show in the menu. No idea about the odd sorting but you are not meant to mess with that file anyway.

In WinX Editor, have you tried prefixing your menu entries with an `&` where you want the underline? Don't know if that will work but it is the standard method for marking the command letter.

Comment: This is the correct answer - adding an ampersand ("&") to the shortcut name immediately prior to the letter you want for the shortcut.