# Is there some kind of official "What's new" for Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

In this new version Windows have changed a lot, but I can't seem to find an official change list/FAQs on how to use new features.
I'm asking because I've read about how to open Charm with keyboard on some 3-rd party site (Win+C). That's not the best way to treat users: when you buy something, you usually have a manual describing how to use the thing you bought (they even ship manuals with the light bulbs...).

Another good example of what I'm talking about described here: [New Windows 8 context menu: official name and documentation?](https://superuser.com/questions/494845/new-windows-8-context-menu-official-name-and-documentation)

In short, I'm looking for something like this http://windows.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows7/products/features and this http://windows.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows7/help/getting-started (preferably in more complete form so it included such a "small" changes like that Win+X context menu).

Comment: As a note to those smart-asses that think that official docs describe everything: did you know that there's an analogue to widget bar in XP, or that by dragging Win7 Explorer's icon from an opened window to some text editor (CMD.exe) will copy path as a string, or maybe you've hear about "God Mode"? Read the question more carefully, you morons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I doubt if it's totally complete, this is Microsoft's official What's New / How-to guide:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/how-to